# Ubuntu 20.04 file browser showing all zfs mounts explicitly in side-panel

Tags: mount, filemanager, zfs

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 on zfs. I had previously had zfs datasets mounted into my 18.04 system. Those mounts are all working in the new system, but they are displaying as mounts in my file browser with unmount buttons next to them. I certainly don't want this function. it is also cluttering my display.

What has changed? How can I fix this?

[file-manager with explicit zfs mounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wru3b.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have reported a bug. No action here :-)
https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1899089